# A question about an irreducible ultra-power

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, banach-algebras, ultrapowers

Let $A$ be a Banach algebra and $E$ be an irreducible Banach $A$-module. Is there a countably incomplete ultra filter $\mathcal U$ on $\mathbb N$, the set of natural numbers, such that the ultra power $(E)_\mathcal U$ becomes an irreducible Banach $A$-module?

(The Banach $A$-module, $E$, which I work with is reflexive, also  $E'$ is an irreducible $A$-module.)

Comment: Surely the embedded copy of $E$ inside $(E)_{\mathcal U}$ will be a proper submodule...

Comment: Every non-principal ultrafilter on $\mathbb N$ is countably incomplete.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question (see my previous comment)

Comment: More precisely $E$ is a (closed) submodule, and is a proper submodule if $\dim(E)=\infty$, so the answer is no. If $\dim(E)<\infty$ is trivially yes. Voting to move to MathSE.